# Hide or remove the historical comments in a git repository

Tags: git, comments

I'd like to open source a private git history, however, I don't want to expose all the historical commit comments to public because it may potentially have company secret. Other than creating a new copy of the repository, what other options do I have? Thanks.

Comment: There are no other options.

Comment: Amend them one by one.

Comment: i think you should edit your question and add a bit of detail. What exactly is it you want to achieve, and why don't you want to "create a new copy of the repository"? After all, everytime someone clones the repo, he creates a new copy of the repo. 

Open sourcing the hisotry almost certainly will require copying the repo, which should not be a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to hide objects in a published repository. Go on with a new cleaned up repo.